# VB 2010 Timer with ToolStripContainer

Tags: vb.net, timer, slider

I'm currently making a simple program. However, I used for loop until to increase the height of the ToolStripContainer act as a slider.
How can I control sliding speed with timer control ?

```
 Do Until ToolStripContainer1.Height = 210
            ToolStripContainer1.Height = ToolStripContainer1.Height + 10
            cmdCalc.Text = "Change"
 Loop
```

Thanks you

Comment: are you saying you want to add a delay inside your `Do/Loop`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the Sleep() method

see more [Sleep Method](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sleep-vbnet)

One simple example:

```
Do Until ToolStripContainer1.Height = 210
        ToolStripContainer1.Height = ToolStripContainer1.Height + 10
        cmdCalc.Text = "Change"
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
End Loop
```

Comment: Sleep method not quite good. When the method is using, the program only runs on that thread make all others controls stop working.

Comment: You could use `Application.DoEvents()` to keep you GUI running.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One more with a timer

```
        Dim t As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
        AddHandler t.Tick, Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
              ToolStripContainer1.Height = ToolStripContainer1.Height + 10
              if ToolStripContainer1.Height = 210 then 
                cmdCalc.Text = "Change"                               
                DirectCast(sender, Timer).Dispose()
              end if
           End Sub
        t.Interval = 250
        t.Start()
```

Creates a timer, adds a handler for the tick, sets the interval (ms) and starts it. When height is 210 it sets the text to "Change" (maybe you need this earlier) and disposes the timer.

Comment: Where you need it ;) ... just replace your current loop with that one.

Comment: Getting this error : Lambda parameter 'sender' and 'e' hide a variable in an enclosing block, a previously defined range variable, or an implicitly declared variable in a query expression.

Comment: so you already have a sender and e var, just change those in the tickhandler O.o